# How can I pass in files from my local directory using either a bash script or Terraform?

Tags: bash, terraform

I have a couple files in my local directory that I would like to pass in to my EC2 instances when they're bootstrapping. I'm not sure how to do this and I don't know if I do this via Terraform or the user-data bash script.

Here's my launch template I'm utilizing in Terraform:

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "this" {
  name                   = "Jira-LT"
  image_id               = data.aws_ssm_parameter.this.value ## TODO Change to variable 
  instance_type          = var.ec2_instance_type
  key_name               = var.ec2_key_pair
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.jira_sg.id]
  user_data              = base64encode(templatefile("../modules/jira/userdata.sh", { efs_id = module.jira.efs_id }))

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 50
    }
  }

  iam_instance_profile {
    name = aws_iam_instance_profile.this_profile.name
  }

  monitoring {
    enabled = true
  }

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"

    tags = {

      Name      = "Jira"
      ManagedBy = "terraform"

    }

  }

  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_90_seconds]


}
```

In the same directory of my terraform code, I have a couple files `server.xml` and `dbconfig.xml`- I would like to add these to certain directories on my instances when they're bootstrapping. Is this something I can do within a bash script? Or Does it need to be done via Terraform?

Comment: You can maybe do it with the template file you have, but take a look at `remote-exec` provisioner as well.

Comment: @MarkoE I know that you can have the `user_data` argument in Terraform specify multiple user-data scripts, in what order do the user-data scripts run? I was thinking a not-so-pretty way would be to have a separate user-data script that contains all of the contents of the file and have that script add the contents, but I'm not sure if Terraform just runs multiple user-data scripts from top-down or if it's a randomized order